# How should i shrink my bash script into 5 for loops?

Tags: bash

I am trying to shrink bash script so it do not have to rerun the same codes over and over again. but according to some people i can run the line at `test` dealing with all 4 encryption at 1 go.

help i do not know what do they meant by that.
Code Gore:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST1=(K F L W )
LIST2=(8 2 9 2 )
LIST3=(x b s v )
LIST4=("~" "-" "[" "*" )
LIST5=("$" "+" "]" "%" )

encr1=".8742cNKlzqQ8Mgjip/Fg1"
salt1="bCgxj8Yt"
encr2="31HvJ8Iinxk2k"
salt2="31"
encr3="AyPVCzU.ourSwFdL3N6/YP9RRfIwwKZPNrnt0/yn5vB"
salt3="klPjs90j"
encr4="Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"
salt4="8899Uidd"

for i in "${LIST1[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST2[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"
            do     
            test="$(mkpasswd -m MD5 "$i$j$k$l$a" -s $salt1 | cut -d"$" -f4)"
            if [ "$test" == "$encr1" ] ; then
            echo " MD5 Salted Hash Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            echo " Salt: "$salt1""

for i in "${LIST1[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST2[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"
            do
   test="$(mkpasswd -m SHA-256 "$i$j$k$l$a" -s $salt3 | cut -d"$" -f4)"
    if [ "$test" == "$encr3" ] ; then
            echo " SHA-256 Salted Hash Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            echo " Salt: "$salt3""
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done

for i in "${LIST1[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST2[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"
            do
   test="$(mkpasswd -m SHA-512 "$i$j$k$l$a" -s $salt4 | cut -d"$" -f4)"
    if [ "$test" == "$encr4" ] ; then
            echo " SHA-512 Salted Hash Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            echo " Salt: "$salt4""

for i in "${LIST1[@]}"
  do
   for j in "${LIST2[@]}"
    do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"
     do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"
        do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"
            do
    test="$(mkpasswd -m des "$i$j$k$l$a" -s $salt2)"
    if [ "$test" == "$encr2" ] ; then
            echo " DES Salted Hash Password is: $i$j$k$l$a"
            echo " Salt: "$salt2""
            exit
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done
        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done


        fi
        done
       done
      done
    done
done
```

The Output still somehow displayed as i wanted:
[image: Output]

Comment: Sorry about the mess, i rarely used stackoverflow.

Comment: You are nesting one loop iterating over `i` within another loop iterating over `i`. This does not make sense.

Comment: @user1934428 i attempted to put everything into 1 loop but i kind of failed at that.

Comment: Then show your failed attempt.

Comment: @user1934428 Understood, but there was no error.

Comment: If there is no error, then we all are happy. Nothing left to do. It's just that in the code you posted, the outer loops over `i` are unnecessary (shaded by the inner ones) and just call the same code over and over again. I wonder how long your script takes to executed, when you do 9765625 calls of `mkpasswd` where 3125 are sufficient. So as a first step, I would simply remove the non-sense five outer loops, and stick with the five inner ones.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for your help, will try to do that. Sorry about the miss-information if caused any.

Comment: BTW, the portable string comparison operator for test is `=`, not `==` (which works by accident).

Answer (score 5):

Since you use the arrays `LIST1` ... `LIST5` only for the 5×`for` constructs I would replace them with brace expansions. That way you end up with only one loop.

Instead of manually listing and checking variable pairs like `encr1` and `salt1` use three arrays `encr`, `salt`, and `algo` (the algorithm you specified manually before). Then you can use a loop to iterate over all these triples instead of having to write each check manually.

```
#! /bin/bash
n=4
encr=(
    ".8742cNKlzqQ8Mgjip/Fg1"
    "31HvJ8Iinxk2k"
    "AyPVCzU.ourSwFdL3N6/YP9RRfIwwKZPNrnt0/yn5vB"
    "Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"
)
salt=(bCgxj8Yt 31 klPjs90j 8899Uidd)
algo=(MD5 SHA-256 SHA-512 des)
for candidate in {K,F,L,W}{8,2,9}{x,b,s,v}{'~','-','[','*'}{'$','+',']','%'}; do
    for (( i = 0; i < n; i++ )); do
        test="$(mkpasswd -m "${algo[i]}" "$candidate" -s "${salt[i]}")"
        if [ "$test" = "${encr[i]}" ]; then
            echo " ${algo[i]} Salted Hash Password is: $candidate"
            echo " Salt: ${salt[i]}"
        fi
    done
done
```

Here I removed the duplicated `2` from the 2nd symbol candidates. Thank you [Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59625328/6770384) for pointing this out.

By the way: I used the variable names from your original script. However, it would be better to name the array of *hashes* something other than `encr`. Hashing and encryption differ – just like shredding a document and then picking ten of its pieces is different from locking the intact document away.

Answer (score 3):

You can loop over all candidates in a single loop with combinatorial `{}` expansion:

```
for candidate in {K,F,L,W}{8,2,9,2}{x,b,s,v}{\~,-,[,\*}{$,+,],%}; do
    ...
done
```

Note that this is not POSIX, but works in bash and zsh.

Answer (score 2):

In the current script, your loops and `if` blocks are all weirdly nested inside each other. The simple way to do this is just have one set of loops that generates candidate passwords, and for each candidate test all 4 hashes:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST1=(K F L W )
LIST2=(8 2 9 2 )
LIST3=(x b s v )
LIST4=("~" "-" "[" "*" )
LIST5=('$' "+" "]" "%" )

encr1=".8742cNKlzqQ8Mgjip/Fg1"
salt1="bCgxj8Yt"
encr2="31HvJ8Iinxk2k"
salt2="31"
encr3="AyPVCzU.ourSwFdL3N6/YP9RRfIwwKZPNrnt0/yn5vB"
salt3="klPjs90j"
encr4="Cd9AjUI4nGglIcP3MByrZUnu.hHBJc7.eR0o/v0A1gu0/6ztFfBxeJgKTzpgoCLptJS2NnliZLZjO40LUseED/"
salt4="8899Uidd"

# Loop over characters to generate candidate passwords
for i in "${LIST1[@]}"; do
  for j in "${LIST2[@]}"; do
    for k in "${LIST3[@]}"; do
      for l in "${LIST4[@]}"; do
        for a in "${LIST5[@]}"; do

          # For this candidate...
          candidate="$i$j$k$l$a"

          # test whether it matches the MD5 hash
          test="$(mkpasswd -m MD5 "$candidate" -s "$salt1" | cut -d'$' -f4)"
          if [ "$test" = "$encr1" ] ; then
            echo " MD5 Salted Hash Password is: $candidate"
            echo " Salt: $salt1"
          fi

          # test whether it matches the SHA-256 hash
          test="$(mkpasswd -m SHA-256 "$candidate" -s "$salt3" | cut -d'$' -f4)"
          if [ "$test" = "$encr3" ] ; then
            echo " SHA-256 Salted Hash Password is: $candidate"
            echo " Salt: $salt3"
          fi

          # test whether it matches the SHA-512 hash
          test="$(mkpasswd -m SHA-512 "$candidate" -s "$salt4" | cut -d'$' -f4)"
          if [ "$test" = "$encr4" ] ; then
            echo " SHA-512 Salted Hash Password is: $candidate"
            echo " Salt: $salt4"
          fi

          # test whether it matches the DES hash
          test="$(mkpasswd -m des "$candidate" -s "$salt2")"
          if [ "$test" = "$encr2" ] ; then
            echo " DES Salted Hash Password is: $candidate"
            echo " Salt: $salt2"
          fi
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

Note that this will find the DES and SHA-512 passwords twice, because "2" is listed twice in `LIST2`.

This approach is a little less efficient than it could be, because it continues checking for matches to the hashes it's already found matches to. This could be fixed in several ways, but they'd all complicate the code more than I want to get into here. In the usual situation, where you're only looking for one match, you can just break out of the loops as soon as you find it.

BTW, I fixed the comparison operator (as @Jens pointed out, `=` is standard in a `[ ]` expression) and quoting (salts were not properly quoted, and using a literal `$` in double-quotes is weird even when it's legal).